# Making CouchDB more searchable and realtime

Tags: php, database, couchdb, real-time

I am having problems figuring out how to use CouchDB best in my scenario (or find another solution which is more suitable). This is an overview of what is needed and I hope I can gain better insight into what I need:

- The system is based almost entirely on keywords.
- Each document has an array of keywords.
- I need to be able to search and return the documents based on keywords.
- I also need to be able to search and return documents based on an incremental ID number
  (eg, all docs with keywords "test OR more" since document id:1318814)
- It all needs to be able to handle hundreds of thousands of documents, realtime updates to
  keywords and would preferably have not much lag (eg, CouchDB view generation so input to being able to output it to a dynamically generated query would only take a few seconds at most).

Would this be possible to do in CouchDB? Are there any good extensions to CouchDB which would allow me to do this?

Edit: **I'm using PHP to connect to the database and Java to feed info into the database.**

Comment: have you considered using full text search engine (e.g., lucene)?

Comment: I have, but to me it seemed a little big for what I need. Though it could be that I don't understand it well enough or am missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is why I wrote CouchDB-Lucene.

https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene

Comment: Thanks, will probe this option a little bit more than I already have!

Comment: @Robert: does couchdb-lucene support facets as well? I'm using Solr at the moment for my 'heavy' products, with a custom Couchdb-solr binding. For more lightweight stuff I would light to dive into couchdb-lucene but faceted-search is a must to me. Also, I understand couchdb-lucene is schemaless right? Would appreciate some insight. Thanks.

Comment: It does not support facets at this time. couchdb-lucene is schemaless,  you must provide a function that converts a couchdb document into a lucene document.